# Errors in Proguard using Eclipse with Universal ImageLoader Library and Animations

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard, universal-image-loader, protected

I am trying to protect my code by applying proguard in my code using eclipse i have used these libraries in my project inside libs folder

1. libs/AndroidViewAnimations-1.1.3.jar
2. libs/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar
3. libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2-with-sources.jar
4. libs/android-support-v4.jar
5. libs/AndroidEasingFunctions-1.0.0.jar

Here is my **Project.properties** content :

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=..\\appcompat
android.library.reference.2=..\\google_play_services\\libproject\\google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.3=../appcompat_v7
android.library.reference.4=../../adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

But i am failed to export APK i am getting following errors in console :

```
    [2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.haarman.listviewanimations.BaseAdapterDecorator: can't find superclass or interface com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersAdapter
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.haarman.listviewanimations.BaseAdapterDecorator: can't find referenced class com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersAdapter
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.haarman.listviewanimations.BaseAdapterDecorator: can't find referenced class com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersAdapter
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.haarman.listviewanimations.BaseAdapterDecorator: can't find referenced class com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersAdapter
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] Warning: there were 13 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-01-14 22:16:23 - MyGallery-master]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] Warning: there were 9 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-01-14 22:25:13 - MyGallery-master]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ListViewAnimations i added the following in my config file:-

```
-dontwarn com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.**
```

Try it and let me know